# MapBox Android application crashes after update to SDK 4.1.0 on emulator

Tags: android, crash, emulation, mapbox

After the update to Android MapBox SDK 4.1.0/4.1.1 my app crashes on Android emulator with:

```
E/mbgl: [Shader]: Vertex shader fill failed to compile: precision highp float;
    #ifdef GL_ES
    precision highp float;
    #else
    #define lowp
    #define mediump
    #define highp
    #endif

    attribute vec2 a_pos;

    uniform mat4 u_matrix;

    void main() {
        gl_Position = u_matrix * vec4(a_pos, 0, 1);
    }

07-23 00:07:06.818 8965-8965/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadcab1 (code=1), thread 8965 (pboxandroiddemo)
```

The app runs without crash on Android physical devices and when compiled with MapBox SDK 4.0.0.

MapBox example on https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo crashes with the same error when compiled locally.

Tested on Linux Mint with following images:

Intel x86 Atom_System Image API 19 Revision 22
Intel x86 Atom_System Image API 23 Revision 15
Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image API 24 Revision 5

Is this known problem? Can this crash affect production build on physical devices? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Crashes occur on Emulator with both mapbox-android-sdk:4.1.0@aar  & mapbox-android-sdk:4.1.1@aar

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a problem with Mapbox, but with the Android emulators and the "Android SDK Tools", at least for macOS.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39731164/388210

Answer (score 2):

For those using the emulator:

This can be fixed by changing your emulated graphics to `Software - GLES 2.0` in your AVD settings. This is not ideal, but it will work (and is still *much* faster than emulating an ARM device).

I suspect this is emulator specific.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you mean Android Mapbox SDK 4.1.0/4.1.1 and not DropBox ;)

First, make sure you are always using the latest version of the SDK, 4.1.1 fixes an important bug that can potentially break your app. This sounds like an issue with the emulator possibly not having OpenGL setup properly. I'm not familiar with Linux Mint but you will need to make sure your graphics driver is installed and up to date. It will also need to be able to support OpenGL 2.0 or higher.

We don't guarantee Mapbox will be able to work on an emulator but we do strive to ensure Mapbox works on as many physical devices as possible. If an emulator must be used, we recommend either the built in Android Studio one or [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/).

Comment: The issue can be replicated on emulator built in Android Studio and on OS X with SDK 4.1.1. So it is probably not problem with OpenGL setup or graphics card. Is there any plan to look at the issue and possibly fix it? MapBox SDK 4.0.0 did not have the problem.

Comment: Please see my answer to this. Using software emulation for graphics seems to solve the issue, supporting your claim that it is an emulator problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this known problem? Can this crash affect production build on
>   physical devices? Is there any workaround?

**Answer** —

- If you crash on a x86 emulator, then there is a *really* good chance it will crash on a x86 device.
- If you pass testing on a ARM device, there is a *really* good chance your app will work fine on ARM devices
- If that doesn't answer your initial question, then there is [Mapbox issue #5456](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/5456#issuecomment-229969470) that has some discussion.

I also saw the same crash on an x86 emulator in OS X with Android Studio.  The same app passed on an ARM device.

As you mentioned, the emulators are `Intel x86 Atom_System` images.

The Mapbox Android SDK compiled in with gradle as an `AAR` file includes several shared objects for different device processors including for ARM, x86 and MIPS.

That is, when you use this

```
compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.1.0@aar')
```

You get several libmapbox-gl.so shared objects in your Android APK

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have verified that this issue does in fact crash Android x86 physical devices.  RemixOS has the exact same crash as can be seen from catlog - if anyone wants the full log - let me know, but its mostly the same as above except that I also have the reg dump and backtrace showing that it was the mapbox SDK that originated the issue.

My guess is that the issue is because most Android x86 devices aren't supporting the ES variant of OpenGL (for embedded devices), but rather the full desktop spec.  This is normally not a concern, but the #ifdef specifically tests for the ES variant and then #define's away a few types that I think need to be defined.  The ES variant sets highp to a float while the non-ES code leaves it blank!   This would cause the compilation problem (basically JIT via LLVM) and then the lack of code and the crash-n-burn.