# MapBox: Shader failed to compile: ERROR: Valid GLSL but not GLSL ES

Tags: android, glsl, mapbox

I'm getting this error when trying to load a MapBox view in my app. Have I gone wrong in the code?

Test info:

> Nexus 5X (API 23) Android 6.0 x86_64 emulator, Android Studio 2.2 Preview 7 (Mac)

Gradle:

```
compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.1.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

MapActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    MapboxAccountManager.start(this, getString(R.string.accessToken));

    // Create a mapView
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    // Doesn't work without using deprecated setAccessToken... bug??
    mapView.setAccessToken(getString(R.string.accessToken));

    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

        }
    });
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

XML:

```
<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    mapbox:style_url="@string/style_mapbox_streets"
    mapbox:center_latitude="41.885"
    mapbox:center_longitude="-87.679"
    mapbox:zoom="12"
    mapbox:tilt="20" />
```

Logs:

```
E/mbgl: [Shader]: Shader failed to compile: ERROR: Valid GLSL but not GLSL ES
E/mbgl: [Shader]: Vertex shader fill failed to compile: precision highp float;
        #ifdef GL_ES
        precision highp float;
        #else
        #define lowp
        #define mediump
        #define highp
        #endif

        attribute vec2 a_pos;

        uniform mat4 u_matrix;

        void main() {
                gl_Position = u_matrix * vec4(a_pos, 0, 1);
        }
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdeadcab1 in tid 22621
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38538157/mapbox-android-application-crashes-after-update-to-sdk-4-1-0-on-emulator/

Comment: Also, please edit your testing information (e.g., device vs emulator, arm vs x86).

Comment: @RobLabs Updated with info

Comment: doovers — thanks.  Yes, I think this is similar/duplicate as mentioned.  I have the same setup as you and I got the same error.  Arm device works fine.  I've rolled back to 4.0.0, so I can test on the emulator.

Comment: @RobLabs Ok I'll work with Arm for now so... Is this issue being tracked on GitHub do you know?

Comment: check the other SO post, there is a Github issue #.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Android studio are you using and are you running your app on an emulator or physical device? tested and was able to produce using the beta version of studio but not the stable.

A side note:

```
MapboxAccountManager.start(this, getString(R.string.accessToken));
```

needs to go before `setContentView()` if you have your mapview within the XML.

Comment: Updated question with requested info