# Mapbox Android SDK crash - "java.lang.Error: Vertex shader fill failed to compile"

Tags: java, android-studio, glsl, mapbox, glsles

After upgrading my Android Studio version to 2.1.3, my application crashes every time I launch it.

More precisely, it crashes when trying to load my Mapbox View (that was perfectly working before that).

I did some research, and it seems to be a known issue, but I couldn't find any workaround to pass through it...

I think it MAY be a problem with the Emulator only, but for now I couldn't try on a lot of physical devices, so I'm not sure about that. But anyway, I really need to use the emulator to debug my app.

If someone has any information about that it will be really helpful. Thank a lot!

Here is the error logs I receive. The first one:

```
09-16 13:27:59.063 2938-2938/flow.bricks D/mbgl: {flow.bricks}[Android]: NativeMapView::notifyMapChange()
09-16 13:27:59.065 2938-2938/flow.bricks E/mbgl: {flow.bricks}[Shader]: Shader failed to compile: ERROR: Valid GLSL but not GLSL ES
09-16 13:27:59.065 2938-2938/flow.bricks E/mbgl: {flow.bricks}[Shader]: Vertex shader fill failed to compile: precision highp float;
                                             #ifdef GL_ES
                                             precision highp float;
                                             #else
                                             #define lowp
                                             #define mediump
                                             #define highp
                                             #endif

                                             attribute vec2 a_pos;

                                             uniform mat4 u_matrix;

                                             uniform lowp vec4 u_color;
                                             uniform lowp float u_opacity;

                                             void main() {
                                                 lowp vec4 color = u_color;
                                                 lowp float opacity = u_opacity;

                                                 gl_Position = u_matrix * vec4(a_pos, 0, 1);
                                             }
09-16 13:27:59.066 2938-2938/flow.bricks D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

And the second one:

```
                                                           --------- beginning of crash
09-16 13:27:59.068 2938-2938/flow.bricks E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                       Process: flow.bricks, PID: 2938
                                                       java.lang.Error: Vertex shader fill failed to compile
                                                           at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.NativeMapView.nativeRender(Native Method)
                                                           at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.NativeMapView.render(NativeMapView.java:139)
                                                           at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:1377)
                                                           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16178)
                                                           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
                                                           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                                                           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2415)
                                                           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
                                                           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
                                                           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
                                                           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                                                           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                                                           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                                                           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                                                           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                                                           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
                                                           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
                                                           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2690)
                                                           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
                                                           at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:281)
                                                           at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:287)
                                                           at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:322)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2615)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2434)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2067)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                        a
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39131399/388210

Comment: Yes I've seen this answer, but sadly changing my emulator graphics settings did not fix the issue for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion I found at https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/issues/415#issue-177023433

I was able to downgrade my `Android SDK Tools` to `25.1.7`, and I was able to launch and successfully load the x86 emulator.

I tested this against https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo.

---

[image]

---

Here is the rest of my setup

- macOS El Capitan 10.11.6
- Android Studio 2.2
- Specific to my mapbox-android-demo compile
- `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'`
- `supportLibVersion = '24.2.0'`
- `buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'`

Comment: Thanks for the response ! I think I will do that. Just one more question : is it safe to completely delete Android Studio from my Macbook, and then install the proper version from scratch?